# Custom Ivy Resolver throws NullPointer Exception in Grails

Tags: grails, dependencies, ivy

I had the following custom resolver defined in the `repositories{...}` block of my BuildConfig.groovy file so that I could get the jars needed to use JAI in my Grails project.

```
mavenRepo "http://www.mygrid.org.uk/maven/repository"
def jbossResolver = new org.apache.ivy.plugins.resolver.URLResolver()
jbossResolver.addArtifactPattern("https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public-jboss/com/sun/media/[module]/[revision]/[artifact]-[revision].[ext]")
jbossResolver.addArtifactPattern("https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public-jboss/javax/media/[module]/[revision]/[artifact]-[revision].[ext]")
jbossResolver.setName("AwesomestJbossResolverEver")
resolver jbossResolver
```

However, whenever I would run `grails refresh-dependencies`, I would get this error:

```
    compile (
        "net.java.dev.jai-imageio:jai-imageio-core-standalone:1.2-pre-dr-b04-2013-04-23",
        "javax.media:jai-core:1.1.3",
        "com.sun.media:jai-codec:1.1.3"
        )
```

The jai-imageio-core-standalone resolved just fine from the http://www.mygrid.org.uk/maven/repository location, but the jai-core and jai-codec files kept throwing this error:

```
| Error Failed to resolve dependencies (Set log level to 'warn' in BuildConfig.groovy for more information):    
- javax.media:jai-core:1.1.3
- com.sun.media:jai-codec:1.1.3
```

With some verbose logging, I found this error:

```
tried https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public-jboss/com/sun/media/jai-codec/1.1.3/jai-codec-1.1.3.jar
null: no ivy file found for com.sun.media#jai-codec;1.1.3: using default data
problem occurred while resolving dependency: com.sun.media#jai-codec;1.1.3 {compile=[default]} with null: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.util.Hashtable.put(Hashtable.java:394)
    at java.util.Properties.setProperty(Properties.java:143)
    at org.apache.ivy.core.cache.DefaultRepositoryCacheManager.saveResolvers(DefaultRepositoryCacheManager.java:422)
    at org.apache.ivy.core.cache.DefaultRepositoryCacheManager.originalToCachedModuleDescriptor(DefaultRepositoryCacheManager.java:875)
......long stack trace here.........
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.support.GrailsStarter.rootLoader(GrailsStarter.java:234)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.support.GrailsStarter.main(GrailsStarter.java:262)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reviewing the [Ivy resolver documentation](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/history/trunk/settings/resolvers.html) and the [DefaultRepositoryCacheManager's saveResolver() method](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/ant/ivy/core/trunk/src/java/org/apache/ivy/core/cache/DefaultRepositoryCacheManager.java)

The problem, I discovered, was that my custom jboss resolver needed a name. I changed that part of my `repositories` block to read:

```
def jbossResolver = new org.apache.ivy.plugins.resolver.URLResolver()
jbossResolver.addArtifactPattern("https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public-jboss/com/sun/media/[module]/[revision]/[artifact]-[revision].[ext]")
jbossResolver.addArtifactPattern("https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public-jboss/javax/media/[module]/[revision]/[artifact]-[revision].[ext]")
jbossResolver.setName("AwesomestJbossResolverEver")
resolver jbossResolver
```

Adding the name with the setName method was all it took to get rid of that nullPointer exception.

Notably, a more careful reading of the Grails documentation would have the [Grails Documentation](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/conf.html#dependencyRepositories) section on custom resolvers would have hinted at the problem, as their custom URLResolver specifies a name and settings property. LFMF